# DQN for dynamic action spaces

Tags: neural-networks, optimization, reinforcement-learning

Are there examples of DQN being effective in exploring dynamic search spaces which could be exponential?
I have come across DQN being used for a lot of game-like settings where every step is one of a fixed set of actions. I am wondering if DQN would be the right strategy for something like solving a maze, or any other optimisation problem, where every instance of the dataset has a different objective. An example would be trying to build a CSP or SAT solver. I have two questions :

1. In case every iteration of the DQN is used on a different problem, how would replay memory utilised?
2. Are there some encoding strategies for the search space which can scale well on (possibly) exponential search spaces?

Comment: can you be more precise about what action space you have in mind? isn't a maze still fixed action space? (you can go in one of 4 cardinal directions per step)

Comment: I have a more general space in mind - for example the maze could have n-dimensions. Or another example could be building SAT or CSP solvers.